# Layout is changing android 4.0 versions

Tags: android, button, textview, android-edittext

I have a layout with open text ,text view and button in my app. That is working fine in all other android os versions but in android 4.0.1 the text in the button text is aligning left and text view data also hiding at touching of the edit text.

Please any one help me in this

Answer (score 0):

I've seen older android versions be more liberal in how they interpret incorrect layouts, whereas android 4.0 being a bit more strict. small things such as a textview having an image source would be resized to the image in older versions of android, but the image size being ignored in android 4.0 because it thinks you should just use an imageview instead

also, post your code